# the best way to exclude some data from a method in sails controller

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I want's to exclude some data in some controller method and in other method i want's that data. I do it with `forEach` function right into method after finding that  :

```
nine: function (req, res) {
    Dore.find()
        .limit(9)
        .sort('createdAt DESC')
        .populate('file')
        .exec(function (err, sh) {
            if (err) {
                return res.negotiate(err);
            } else {
                console.log('before : ', sh);
                sh.forEach(function (item, i) {
                    delete item.zaman;
                });
                console.log('after : ', sh);
                return res.send(sh);
            }
        });
},
```

I want to know how possible to do that with finding and do not included ever in finding so we don't need to remove that again with `forEach`.
tanks

As @zabware say we have `select` method in `Query option` I try this format but do not work and return all data :

I try to use that with following format but don't working :

```
Model.find( {
            where: {},
            limit: 9,
            sort: 'createdAt DESC'
        },
        {
            select: [ 'id', 'createdAt' ]
        } )
```

and

```
Model.find( {
            where: {},
            limit: 9,
            sort: 'createdAt DESC',
                        select: [ 'id', 'createdAt' ]
        } )
```

and

```
Model.find( {}, select: [ 'id', 'createdAt' ] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [**toJson**](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json) is really designed to solve the kind of problem you are facing, it will not help you, since in some actions you want to exclude certain fields and in others not.

So we need to select fields per query. Luckily there is a solution for this in waterline:

```
Dore.find({}, {select: ['foo', 'bar']})
    .limit(9)
    .sort('createdAt DESC')
    .populate('file')
    .exec(function (err, sh) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(sh);
    });
```

This is supported since sails 0.11 but not really documented. You can find it under query options here https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/e7b9ecf2510646b7de69663f709175a186da10d5/queries/query-language.md#query-options

Comment: `toJson` remove it from all method in other method in controller i want that data

Comment: @SydAmir okay then the select query option might suit you better. See my update.

Comment: I try in several way but did not work, and when use select query option do the query twice i don't know for what( loges in console twice).

Comment: my sails version is 0.12.3, in node 4.2.6, and npm version 3.10.6, in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Query it one time i have a mistake(opened project in 2 window - refreshed automatically)

Comment: @SydAmir it works for me. You must be doing something wrong. I updated my answer with more code.

Comment: I do exactly what you do ... but return all fields for me(!?).  I do it with  [.native](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native) and get the exact field i want but i don't know how populate association with `.native()`

Comment: @SydAmir dont use native. In your code I see where: {}, remove that.

Comment: however the `select` is the right method sails defined for this issue. I try it carefully again.

Comment: I removed `where: {}` and do it in several way but return all fields

Comment: @SydAmir what database system are you using?

Comment: @SydAmir hm so this is not the problem. I tested with mongodb also.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally stumbled upon it while playing with the debugger - Sails version `1.2.3`

There is something like `omit` and You can put it into your find method call:

```
const user = await User.findOne({
   where: {email : inputs.email},
   omit: ['password']
}); //There won't be password field in the user object
```

It is a pity that there is no word about it in the documentation.