# Waterline + Sails.js: Sort documents without the sort field to end of results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I have a model Event.js:

```
var Event = {
    schema: true,
    attributes: {
        time: {
            type: "datetime"
            // There can be events which don't have 'time' field
        }
        // Some more fields, some of which connect to other models
    }
}
module.exports = Event;
```

I want to fetch all events based on time. They should be sorted in ascending order by `time` but all the events without `time` should be pushed to the last.

How can I do this without using `.native()`? I do not want to use 'native' because I also want to populate several fields in `Event`.

**EDIT:**

Lets say I have the following documents in the collection:

```
// For simplicity I am using human readable date format
{id: 1, time: "5th Jan 2017"}
{id: 2}
{id: 3, time: "14th Dec 2016"}
{id: 4, time: "3rd Mar 2017"}
{id: 5}
```

They should be sorted like this:

```
{id: 3, time: "14th Dec 2016"}
{id: 1, time: "5th Jan 2017"}
{id: 4, time: "3rd Mar 2017"}
{id: 2}
{id: 5}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the best way to exclude some data from a method in sails controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484407/the-best-way-to-exclude-some-data-from-a-method-in-sails-controller)

Comment: @zabware how will that solve my issue. I want that the documents not containing the field 'time' to be pushed to last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sails.js transform `null` fields into an "low value" attribute for sorting. There is two possible workarounds.

The first one, is using the `defaultsTo` attribute setting it to an invalid value like `"ǸA"`. But you cannot use `datetime` for validation and must create a custom validation, that tries to create a date, and check if it's valid.

Your model will be:

```
time: {
  type: "string",
  defaultsTo: "NA"
}
```

And use a custom validation to guarantee that your string is an date using [Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) library with:

```
Moment(myDate).isValid()
```

Depending of your DB. There is no real advantage of using a Date field over an string field validated as an `IsoDate String`. I've tested it on **MongoDB**.

You can find lots of examples of custom validations in [sails documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations).

---

Another alternative. And much more simple, is just filter null fields, to not show it.
Then you need to make two calls to the API, but you can encapsulate it, into an controller function.

To filter null field in blueprints API. Will be:

`http://localhost:1337/event/where={"time":{"!":null}}`

Comment: My business logic is such that I cannot have `time` field non-empty for some records.

Comment: If your business logic cannot have an empty time field. What do you mean by: "but I want all the events without any time to be pushed to the last."

Comment: "I cannot have `time` field non-empty" = "time field can be empty" for some records. Sorry for the double negative before.

Comment: I understood your question now. And made a few tests, it looks like waterline defaults empty fields on sort to an invalid low value character, but it will always show.

But you can supress and use it separatelly by using blueprints API with:
`localhost:1337/event/where={"time":{"!":null}}`

There is two possible workarounds, but sadly, no direct solution. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks @gustavo I did it in a similar fashion suggested by you. I realized it can't be done with a single call :(